# DNN 5 - DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl() throws NullReferenceException

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

**Posting as a reference**

when redirecting to custom controls in custom DNN 5 module, I get

```
InnerException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Method: DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl
StackTrace:
Message: DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was resolved by making sure that ALL custom controls inherit from **PortalModuleBase**

Answer (score 0):

To me, it worked when the .ascx.cs control inherit from DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleSettingsBase